# next/prev UIButtons not responding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiview, uibutton

I have a Title View defined as follows : (The Colored boxes are the frames for the respective objects)

[image]

```
LeftMost Red Box            : UIButton   : BackButton
White Box                   : UIView     : LabelsView, Contains Label 1 & Label 2
Green Box + Text            : UILabel    : Label 1
Red Box   + Text            : UILabel    : Label 2
Second White Box            : UIView     : NavigationButtonView, Contains Next And Previous Button
Two Rightmost Green Boxes   : UIButtons  : Next and Previous Button
```

All of the above goes into

```
UIView * myTitleBar;
```

The **BackButton** is working and its respective selector is being called on "Touch Up Inside" Event.

But the **Next** and **Previous** UIButtons defined as follows :

```
    UIButton *prevImageButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, navButtonWidth, navButtonHeight)];
    [prevImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prevImageButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [prevImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    
    UIButton *nextImageButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(navButtonWidth + navButtonWidth, 10, navButtonWidth, navButtonHeight)];
    [nextImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextImageButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [nextImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

do not respond.

nextImageButtonPressed is defined as follows :

```
- (IBAction)nextImageButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Function Called");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What might be causing this issue ?
I have tried adding the buttons using

```
[titleBarLabelView insertSubview:navigationButtonView atIndex:1000];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavigationButtonView` was being assigned as a `subView` of `LabelsView` instead of `myTitleBar`. So even though it was visible, the user cannot interact with it, as it is being clipped.